# Finding the difference between 2 dates

Tags: php

I made this and needed some help tweaking it so that it gives the proper outcome

```
function daysDifference($end){
    //$start = "2007-03-24";
    //$end = "2009-06-26";
    $now = date("Y-m-d");
    $e = (is_string($end) ? strtotime($end) : $end);

    $diff = abs($e - strtotime($now));

    $years = floor($diff / (365 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    $months = floor(($diff - $years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24) / (30 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    $days = floor(($diff - $years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24 - $months * 30 * 60 * 60 * 24)/ (60 * 60 *24));

    return ($years == 0 ? '' : ($years == 1 ? $years . ' year ' : $years . ' years ')) . ($months == 0 ? '' : ($months == 1 ? $months . ' month ' : $months . ' months ')) . ($days == 0 ? '' : ($days == 1 ? $days . ' day ' : $days . ' days '));
}
```

`$end` is being pulled from my database so there is checks to see if its a string or a date already.

`$e` now can be used, but when I tried to subtract `$now` from `$e` I get funny results

for instance:

`$now` being today the `13th` and `$e` being an end date for a project, it's suppose to give me what I need... right?

Where I'm suppose to get say 12 days remaining, I get 1 year 12 days.

and where `$e = 0000-00-00` (in case the user didn't input an end date), I get 40 years 10 months and 26 days remaining.

I tried alot of different variations to my calculations but I keep getting nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store real dates, not strings, and you can just ask the database for the difference.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, end) FROM table
```

If you just go dividing things by 365 you won't get accurate results. Not every year has 365 days.

Answer (score 4):

Why would you reinvent the wheel? Use [date_diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php):

```
<?php
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%d days');
?>
```

Comment: my php skills are moderate, reinventing the wheel comes along with that lol. date_diff hmmm. I'll take a closer look! Thanks

Comment: @s2xi whenever you feel like making a generic function, look it up on php.net first, you might be surprised!